# Trying to access Redis via React: Can't resolve 'hiredis'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redis

I've created a simple react app via `create-react-app` and I'm trying to access my Redis DB using the node redis client.

When I start up my app, I receive the following error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in
>   '/Users/Joseph/workspace/chatbots/diagnosis-bot/symptom-search/node_modules/redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib'

I have a feeling it is because redis is actually made for node and not react, but still want to know whether there is any workaround this without having to make a separate back-end node app just to access Redis.

Comment: Does any warning or notice display when you type `npm ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any way you could connect to Redis without an intermediary using React.

There are security issues with trying to connect directly to Redis from a front-end application: you would have to expose users to your connection details.

Comment: Gotcha. Just wanted to clarify. Thanks :)